# Is it possible to add text/image watermark using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to add text/image watermark to a video using ffmpeg without re-encoding. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Softsubs

You can add text without re-encoding by using any softsubs subtitles format such as SRT, ASS, SSA, VTT.

SRT example:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
Using the SRT subs

2
00:00:07,000 --> 00:00:14,000
<font color="red>The color is red</font>
```

Mux into video file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subs.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

## Hardsubs

If you want to "burn-in" text (aka hardsubs), such as by using the *drawtext*, *subtitles*, or *ass* filters **then you must re-encode** because filters require encoding.

## Use a player

You can use a player to add the text during playback. Example using the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='boring text example'" input.mp4
```

## HTML5

Use [WebVTT subtitles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebVTT).

```
<video controls autoplay src="video.webm">
  <track default src="subtitles.vtt">
</video>
```